# File being used by another process in windows service

Tags: c#, file, quartz.net, topshelf

I have written following code which runs fine but problem is that sometimes it gives me `file being used by another process` these two jobs are accessing and writing the same file. `ClickProfileJob` runs first and repeats after 5 seconds and then the second job `ClickLikeJob` according to schedule of 5 seconds. I have seen couple of solutions which had suggested the same `using`technique which I have coded below.

```
    using Quartz;
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using Topshelf;
    using Topshelf.Quartz;

    namespace FinyaConsole
    {
     class Program
     {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            userCreds creds = new userCreds();

            if (creds.checkUser().Length > 3)
            {
                HostFactory.Run(x =>
                {
                    x.Service<GiveHeartsService>(s =>
                    {
                        s.WhenStarted(service => service.OnStart());
                        s.WhenStopped(service => service.OnStop());
                        s.ConstructUsing(() => new GiveHeartsService());

                        s.ScheduleQuartzJob(q =>
                            q.WithJob(() =>
                                JobBuilder.Create<ClickProfileJob>().Build())
                                .AddTrigger(() => TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                    .WithSimpleSchedule(b => b
                                        .WithIntervalInSeconds(5)
                                        .RepeatForever())
                                    .Build()));

                        s.ScheduleQuartzJob(q =>
                            q.WithJob(() =>
                                JobBuilder.Create<ClickLikeJob>().Build())
                                .AddTrigger(() => TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                    .WithSimpleSchedule(b => b
                                        .WithIntervalInSeconds(5)
                                        .RepeatForever())
                                    .Build()));


                    });

                    //.DependsOnEventLog()

                    x.RunAsLocalSystem()
                        .StartAutomaticallyDelayed()
                        .EnableServiceRecovery(rc => rc.RestartService(1));

                    x.SetServiceName("FinyaHearts");
                    x.SetDisplayName("FinyaHearts");
                    x.SetDescription("This is a service.");
                });
            }
        }
    }
        public class ClickProfileJob : IJob
        {
            public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(".\\visits_to_others.txt", true))
                    {

                        //Write a line of text
                        sw.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now}] Welcome from ClickProfileJob!");
                        Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now}] Welcome from ClickProfileJob!");
                        //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"path\visit_users.txt", userLink);
                        //Close the file
                        sw.Flush();
                        sw.Dispose();
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
                }
            }
        }

        public class ClickLikeJob : IJob
        {
            public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(".\\visits_to_others.txt", true))
                    {

                        //Write a line of text
                        sw.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now}] Welcome from ClickLikeJob!");
                        Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now}] Welcome from ClickLikeJob!");
                        //System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"path\visit_users.txt", userLink);
                        //Close the file
                        sw.Flush();
                        sw.Dispose();
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you've effectively got 2 timers firing (more-or-less) at the same time every 5 seconds. These invoke different methods respectively that both attempt to write to the same file. Boom. Why not have a single timer that invokes a method that invokes the original methods ***sequentially***? That way, their execution will never overlap.

Comment: @spender I have tried changing seconds like 2 seconds for the first job and 7 seconds for the second job. It still sometimes gives the error. These two jobs are different because I want to use the first one to run like every week and the second job is timed to run after 3 days.

Comment: After 14 seconds? Think about it.

Comment: 'Why not have a single timer that invokes a method that invokes the original methods sequentially?' any example?

Comment: How long do these processes take? You could integrate a `while...try...catch` combo to make this a quasi-asynchronous task to wait for Job1 to be finished before Job2 executes

Comment: This is not a Quartz specific problem. Just use a `SemaphoreSlim` to control the lock for the File.

Comment: @Rabban I have no experience with `SemaphoreSlim`, How can I use it in this file lock scenario?

Comment: @Amjad you can even use a normal `lock` to achieve this. I have currently no time to wirte an answer but i will later, if nobody provided an answer till then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Quartz specific problem. You can use a `SemaphoreSlim` or better a simple `lock`. Just create a base job and derive your other Jobs from it. Then lock the `LockObject` in both Jobs.

```
public abstract class LockableJobBase
{
    protected static object LockObject = new object();
}


public class ClickProfileJob : LockableJobBase, IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (LockObject)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(".\\visits_to_others.txt", true))
                {
                    // your sw stuff
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
        }
    }
}

public class ClickLikeJob : LockableJobBase, IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (LockObject)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(".\\visits_to_others.txt", true))
                {
                    // your sw stuff
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know how to use locks effectively, would you recommend any good book that teaches these kind of advanced topics?

Comment: Glad i could help ;) There are plenty of books that are a good read but the basics are easy and you really don't need a book for this. It is more important that you know, where and how to use different patterns and techniques. StackOverflow should be the first choice when you have questions and there are a lot other good site out the like CodeProject. Ps: please don't ask on SO for Books or Tutorials or stuff like this. It's considered as offtopic and will be closed.